# SAML can a non PingFederate SP be connected with a PingFederate IdP?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, federation, pingfederate

I'm a newcomer to the SAML world.

We have a project where the website (PHP) needs to be able to read SAML assertions from a PingFederate IdP server. I'd like to know whether it is possible to use [OneLogin's SAML PHP Toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) (or any other tool) as an SAML SP or if it is mandatory to have a Ping Federate server configured as an SP (as stated in the [PHP Integration Kit requirements](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PHP251/Introduction)).

Would there be extra obstacles doing so ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Ping Identity's PHP Integration Kit, you must be licensed for and using PingFederate.

For you, acting as the SP, there is no requirement for you to use PingFederate or the PHP Integration Kit offered by Ping Identity. You are free to use any SAML-compliant tool kit.